# Python as an executable program

Tags: python, linux, icons, exe

When I use programs like gimp or so, there's always a file that I click on to execute the program.

I'd like to know how to do that in Python. I'm using Linux and Tkinter but I'd like to run my application on every platform. For this I want to have something that works as an executable. Could you please give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can simply include a shebang that specifies the path to Python, so you can just click on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

In Windows, it's not as simple. There are programs that compiles a Python script to an executable file, but Linux can't handle PE formats anyway.